# PHP - Run through If statements, if none are true, echo a random variable

Tags: php, variables, random, echo

Ok what I would like to do is somewhat unique, and I can't find anything online to guide me, so hopefully I do a good job explaining it.

**PROBLEM:**

I have a series of `if` statements in PHP. To simplify, each `if` statement looks like this:

```
if($product_name == 'shoe') {
     $shoe_description = '<p>Shoe description</p>';
     echo $shoe_description;
}
else if($product_name == 'car') {
     $car_description = '<p>Car description</p>';
     echo $car_description;
}
else if($product_name == 'bottle') {
     $bottle_description = '<p>Bottle description</p>';
     echo $bottle_description;
}
```

This works fine as long as `$product_name` is defined as one of my variables.  What I would like to do is, as the last statement, say that "**if `product_name` matches none of my variables, show a random description from above**"; so I'll add a final `else` statement to the end of the above code (example - not working code):

```
else {
     // Show one of the echo strings from above (i.e. $car_description)
     //but pick randomly
}
```

**QUESTION:**

What code would I need to edit/add so that the final else statement picks one of the 3 `description` variables so that I can then `echo` it on the page?

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? `$product_name = 'shoe'` is probably better like this: `$product_name == 'shoe'` ? Otherwise it doesn't make too much sense

Comment: @Nanne Thanks I updated it. I simplified my code to make it easier to explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a pretty basic rewrite of the logic you gave. You can usually rewrite a series of if statements into simpler logic, or into a switch statement—depending on what you're trying to accomplish. In this case, I'd check if the `$product_name` has a description and otherwise just pick a random key.

```
$product_name = $_SESSION['product_name'];

$descriptions = array(
    'shoe' => '<p>Shoe description</p>',
    'car' => '<p>Car description</p>',
    'bottle' => '<p>Bottle description</p>',
);

if(isset($product_name) && isset($descriptions[$product_name])) {
    echo $descriptions[$product_name];
} else {
    echo $descriptions[array_rand($descriptions)];
}
```

Comment: Wow you post exactly the answer I was written!

Comment: Haha, nice :) Thinking in the same way :)

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov Agreed. That's what we're here for.

Comment: +1 I think this is the most appropriate way. But I would probably exclude the <p> tag from the descriptions (unless it's not consistent with all the descriptions) ;)

Comment: @Ignas this is just to give an idea how it may look like. What inside descriptions doesn't matter :)

Comment: See question in comment on above answer

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov yeah I agree, just thought that would be good for the guy to know :)

Comment: Is this actually checking what `$product_name` is set to? The variable `$product_name` is being defined elsewhere on the page, so I need to check what it is set to in order to decide which description to display, or the random one.

Comment: @AdamD This is checking if the `$descriptions` array contains an element with the key of `$product_name`. This is why it works.

Comment: It's not working. I don't think it's checking what `$product_name` is set to.

Comment: @AdamD Perhaps you need a `global $product_name` if the variable comes from another script. This must be local to the script/method this code is in.

Comment: Ah - The `$product_name` is actually a `$_SESSION` variable. Can I put this in place of `$product_name` or do I need to set it locally first?

Answer (score 2):

```
$descriptions = array(
    'shoe' => '<p>Shoe description</p>',
    'car' => '<p>Car description</p>',
    'bottle' => '<p>Bottle description</p>'
);

if(isset($product_name) && isset($descriptions[$product_name])){
    echo $descriptions[$product_name];
} else {
    echo $descriptions[array_rand($descriptions)];
}
```

Comment: Is this actually checking what `$product_name` is set to?

Comment: My code fullfils OP's condition `"if product_name matches none of my variables, show a random description from above"`. Well, I rewrote the code to be more close to what OP want

Comment: Can you explain what `if(isset($product_name) && isset($descriptions[$product_name]))` is actually checking? Thanks

Comment: Basically its simple english :) which can be translated from english to my bad english as "if `$product_name` exists and if `$descriptions` array contains a key with value of `$product_name` then take value from array with a key which `$product_name` variable has" So if `$product_name` equals 'car' you'll get description for 'car'. I suggest you to learn the basics of programming. [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php)

Comment: I understand how the code works. I don't need the low blows. Your code does not work.

Comment: I added the semicolon. See my last comment on the above answer... looks like it's b/c when simplifying my code, I forgot `$product_name` is actually a session variable. Can I insert that or do i need to set it locally first?

Comment: @AdamD you can use whatever you want instead of `$product_name` or just assign to `$product_name` your session variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to put your products and descriptions in a key/value pair array.

That way you can shorten your if statement, and pick one randomly (by generating a random index) in the `else` case without defining your descriptions twice.

-- edit --

Robert K/Alexander Larikov beat me to it :) See theirs for sample code.

Comment: Check my comments on their answers - Seems like people are too busy having a convo instead of explaining lol

Comment: @AdamD `isset` checks if the variable is set and not `NULL`. So in the given code they check if `$product_name` is set and then if `$descriptions[$product_name]` is set (and thus, if `$product_name` is in the array) if it is, then it gives back the corresponding text according to `$product_name`, else it will take a random value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
if(!$product_name){
      $options = array('shoe','car','bottle');
      $product_name = array_rand($options);
}
//your code here.
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this implementation. However, it does require extra logic when compared to what several of us came up with.

Comment: I choose this because the OP's code is (I think) some abstraction of the real code. This is closest to what the OP already "has", so might be easier to incorporate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
//$product_name = ...
$list = array('shoe' => 'Shoe description', 'car' => 'Car description', 'bottle' => 'Bottle description');
echo '<p>';
if (isset($list[$product_name])) {
   echo $list[$product_name];
} else {
   echo $list[array_rand($list)];
}
echo '</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just put all the bottle descriptions into an array and if you hit the final `else` just pull a random value from the array

```
$descriptions   = array(
    'shoe'      => 'Shoe description',
    'car'       => 'Car description',
    'bottle'    => 'Bottle description'
);

if($product_name = 'shoe') {
     $shoe_description = '<p>'.$descriptions[$product_name].'</p>';
     echo $shoe_description;
}
else if($product_name = 'car') {
     $car_description = '<p>'.$descriptions[$product_name].'</p>';
     echo $car_description;
}
else if($product_name = 'bottle') {
     $bottle_description = '<p>'.$descriptions[$product_name].'</p>';
     echo $bottle_description;
}
else {
    echo '<p>'.$descriptions[array_rand($descriptions)].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Patrick, `array_rand` will return the key, not the value. See my answer.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can do the following:

```
$product_names = array('shoe', 'car', 'bottle');
if (!in_array($product_name, $product_names))
    $product_name = $product_names[rand(0,2)];
```

And then add your code.

Answer (score -4):

I would use a switch statement for this.

```
$strings = array('<p>Shoe description</p>', '<p>Car description</p>', '<p>Bottle description</p>');

switch($product_name)
{
case "shoe":
echo $strings[0];
break;

case "car":
echo $strings[1];
break;

case "bottle":
echo $strings[2];
break;

default:
echo $strings[rand(0,2)];
break;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but, seriously with the downvotes? This works for the OP's problem, if product_name doesn't match it defaults to a random string.

Comment: It's a very ugly and wrong way to do what OP want. How will you maintain your code if there will be 1000 products? What's relation between `'shoe'` and number `0`.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov It still answers the question, meaning it is useful, and what if OP doesn't have 1000 products and they just wanted a quick way of doing a couple products? This would be perfectly fine. They didn't say they had a database of products.

Comment: do you really do not understand why your code can be used? It's a bad practice and because of answers like that newbies wasn't able to write a good code. If you will need to add new description as first element of array you will need to rewrite almost all code

Comment: I understand what you are saying but its not bad practice if those AREN'T your use cases. If your use case is only for these 3, this is perfectly fine. Which the OP says in his question: `What code would I need to edit/add so that the final else statement picks one of the 3 description variables so that I can then echo it on the page?`

Comment: Also, OP doesn't seem to understand your answer even though its correct.